# Saving RDD as sequence file in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, sequencefile

I am able to run this script to save the file in text format, but when I try to run saveAsSequenceFile it is erroring out. If any one have idea about how to save the RDD as sequence file, please let me know the process. I tried looking for solution in "Learning Spark" as well as official Spark documentation.

This runs successfully

```
dataRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/sqoop_import/departments")
dataRDD.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/pyspark/departments")
```

This fails

```
dataRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/sqoop_import/departments")
dataRDD.saveAsSequenceFile("/user/cloudera/pyspark/departmentsSeq")
```

> Error: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsSequenceFile. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD element of type java.lang.String
>   cannot be used

Here is the data:

```
2,Fitness
3,Footwear
4,Apparel
5,Golf
6,Outdoors
7,Fan Shop
8,TESTING
8000,TESTING
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sequence files are used to store key-value pairs so you cannot simply store `RDD[String]`. Given your data I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([
    "2,Fitness", "3,Footwear", "4,Apparel"
])
rdd.map(lambda x: tuple(x.split(",", 1))).saveAsSequenceFile("testSeq")
```

If you want to keep whole strings just use `None` keys:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (None, x)).saveAsSequenceFile("testSeqNone")
```

Comment: when I try to read the file in python it is working fine, but not in scala. I am getting duplicate values when I run this command on data with sequence file format `sc.sequenceFile("/user/cloudera/pyspark/departmentsSeq",classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text]).collect().foreach(println)`

Comment: You got types wrong. And if this is not the case please ask a separate question with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

To write to Sequence file you need the data in format of Hadoop API.

String as Text
Int as IntWritable

In Python :

```
data = [(1, ""),(1, "a"),(2, "bcdf")]
sc.parallelize(data).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(path,"org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat","org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable","org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")
```

Comment: I know how to do it scala. I am looking for pyspark.